# doctrine 2, inserting in entities with assocication

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I have two entities:

Payment and Company.

Payment entity has association to Company entity like this:

```
/**
* @OneToOne(targetEntity="Companies")
* @JoinColumn(name="company_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $total;
```

Why is this association called on insert?

I need to set some stuff (insert) into payments table and I am getting error.

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'company_id' cannot be null
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch (or create) your $company entity first, and then hand it to the $payment before saving. Something like:

```
// First get the company that should be related to the new payment    
$company = $entityManager->getRepository('Company')->find($companyId);

// Attach it to our new payment
$payment->setCompany($company); // Or whatever the setter is in your entity class

// Now we can save
$entityManager->persist($payment);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Thank you I will try this and let you know about result.

Comment: I just do not understand why do I have to do this? I mean, with this association I just wanted to do select, can you explain me why do I have to set $company?

Comment: You just want to do a select? Your original question said "Why is this association called on insert?" I'm confused. If you are doing a select, then Doctrine should fetch the _existing_ company relationship from the database. If you are inserting/saving, then you have to _give_ Doctrine the relationship to save. Make sense?

Comment: I made this association because of select. Why is it called on insert? That is my question.

Comment: Is it possible that your database is not allowing null values in the company_id column?

Comment: Yes, database does not allow null values in company_id column. I am setting this with $payment->setCompany_id($value) but that set get ignored because of that assocication.